# Handling input from user and saving it as an "son "object and later on opening it?

Tags: python, json, input

Hi Iam new to coding but want to learn I have written this cod that lets the user insert an input and that should later save it as a text file(.txt) with json and then later I want open file as (.txt) file to later be able to modify the information as needed.

When I save the user information the content of the file looks like this:

```
{"Titel": "kalle"}{"Titel": "peter"}{"Titel": "kim"}{"Titel": "sena"}
```

But when I want to open that file with this commando:

```
import json

with open('testtitel.txt') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

print(json_data)
```

This text appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openjson.py", line 4, in <module>
    json_data = json.load(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 19 (char 18)
```

What is wrong if somebody could show what needs to be changed and explain as Iam new to coding I will add the code as well.

```
enter code
```

```html
import json


class infoCd():
    def __init__(self, EnTitel):
        self.EnTitel = EnTitel
        # //load to json dic function sa simon
    def make_dict(self):
        the_dict = {"Titel":self.EnTitel}
        return the_dict

    def readFromDict(self, inputDict):
        self.EnTitel = inputDict["Titel"]

    def display_cd_details(self):
        print(" Title: {}  ".format(self.EnTitel))


    def see_details(self):
        with open('testtitel.txt') as json_file:
            testtitel = json.load(json_file)
            for p in testtitel:
                print(p)    
        
def save_cd_details(cd):
    with open('testtitel.txt', 'a') as txtfile:
        json.dump(cd.make_dict(), txtfile)     


def insert_cd_details():
    counter = 0
    lista = []
    while(True):
        EnTitel = input("Insert a titel: ")
        counter+=1

        Cd = infoCd(EnTitel )
        lista.append(Cd)
        print(lista)

    
        save_cd_details(Cd)
        avslutaCd = input(" Do you still want to(j/n)")
        if (avslutaCd   == "j"):
            print("JAAA")
        else:
            print("Nej")
            break  

    return lista    
    

a = insert_cd_details()
for cd in a:
    cd
print(a)





 // code to open
 
 
with open('testtitel.txt') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

print(json_data)
```

here

Comment: from the content of the file - `{"Titel": "kalle"}{"Titel": "peter"}{"Titel": "kim"}{"Titel": "sena"}` it looks that the content is not a JSON format and hence cannot be parsed to a dict in python

Comment: I took the liberty to change the file content to tweak and make it JSON object. check the below content it could work in you case - 

`
{
  "Titels": [
    {
      "Titel": "kalle"
    },
    {
      "Titel": "peter"
    },
    {
      "Titel": "kim"
    },
    {
      "Titel": "sena"
    }
  ]
}
`

Comment: thanks all for the help but how do I save so beacomes a JSON format in def insert_cd_details():

Answer (score 0):

The string you are trying to decode is not valid JSON. I think you want this instead:

```
[{"Titel": "kalle"}, {"Titel": "peter"}, {"Titel": "kim"}, {"Titel": "sena"}]
```